# Returning value from function and inserting to Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey I'm building a simple pace calculator using Tkinter. I managed to get 2 values which are needed for my calculation and I want to return my calculation in the third Entry widget. I've got two functions that returns the `get_value` to console window. Next I want to do the calculations on `get_value` and `get_value1` and insert into the third entry box.

Also can someone explain to me why in the `return_min` and `return_sec` functions need `en` parameter to work?

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()
top.title("Pace Calculator")


def return_min(en):
    get_value = E1.get()
    get_value = int(get_value)
    get_value *= 2
    print(get_value)


def return_sec(en):
    get_value = E2.get()
    get_value = int(get_value)
    get_value *= 3
    print(get_value)


L1 = Label(top, text="minutes")
L1.grid(row=0, column=0)

E1 = Entry(top, bd=5)
E1.grid(row=1, column=0)
E1.bind('<Return>', return_min)

L2 = Label(top, text=" seconds")
L2.grid(row=2, column=0)

E2 = Entry(top, bd=5)
E2.grid(row=3, column=0)
E2.bind('<Return>', return_sec)

L3 = Label(top, text = "Pace")
L3.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

E3 = Entry(top, bd=5)
E3.grid(row=5, column=0)


top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you want to display the results of the calculation in the third Entry widget? Entry widgets are designed to accept user input, not display output. You _can_ put output in an Entry, but that's normally only done when you want the user to modify that output and resubmit the modified data. As for your second question, try printing `en` inside your `return_min` or `return_sec` callbacks and see what it says.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can be useful:   https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSj3Nn_zeqWFnBusqvsjMqF

Comment: @PM2Ring I printed the result of'(en) inside my function and it says <tkinter.Event object at 0x1031ea5f8>

Comment: @Maxxer Exactly. When you use `.bind` the callback function receives the Tkinter Event object that triggered the callback. You can extract useful data from that object. See the docs for details.

Comment: BTW, the easiest way to display something to the user is with a Label. You can call a Lebel's `.config` method to change its text to a different string. Labels can contain multi-line text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "insert" some value into your `E3` `tkinter.Entry`, you can do this:

```
E3.delete(0, END)
E3.insert(0, your_value)
```

I must say that `Entry` widgets are meant for input data, not output! But I can tell you are just getting started and trying things out, so let me know if you need more help with this.

Comment: Ok I get it, so the best way to show a output is to use tkinter.Message  or something else t?

Comment: @Maxxer yes you can do that! It really depends on your end goal. If you are just trying to learn python and tkinter: try all the different ways you can return your value and get comfortable with how the tkinter works and what widgets are meant for what kind of input/output. If you'r just using it for a quick calculation, leave as it is! The Message widget can get annoying if, for every calculation you need to close the pop up window.

Comment: I'm trying to insert my value with the Text.insert(0, get_value) method but still getting NameError: name 'get_value' is not defined. I'm guessing that get_value is only inside the function and I can't access it outside. Any tips?

Comment: You are correct. why don't you create a button widget that, once clicked, `.get`s the values from `E1` and `E2` and than `.insert`s your computer value into `E3`

Comment: Thanks for help! I'm now using button with `command` function which is doing everything from getting inputs from `E1` and `E2` using `.get()` converting pace and inserting it to `E3`. Works perfect.